# Handle form in rendered controller

Tags: php, symfony

I have a page where I list some tasks and there is a form to add a task.
I want to handle the form is another action in the controller but all the stuff is in one page. So I render an action in my template.

There my controller:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{        
    return $this->render("MathieuTestBundle:Default:index.html.twig");
}

public function addAction(Request $request) {
    $task = new Task();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add("task", "text")
        ->add("expiration", "date", array("format" => "ddMMyy"))
        ->add("save", "submit")
        ->getForm();

    return $this->render("MathieuTestBundle:Default:add.html.twig", array(
        "form" => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

There my index.html.twig template:

```
<h1>Tasks:</h1>

<ul>
    <li>Wash the dog</li>
    <li>Do homework</li>
    <li>Learn Symfony</li>
</ul>

{{render(controller("MathieuTestBundle:Default:add"))}}
```

And my add.html.twig template:

```
{{form(form)}}
```

Actually I use my template add.html.twig to handle the form and the index.html.twig template to list all my tasks.

The problem is I can't handle the form because the action that does it is rendered by the index.html.twig template.

How can I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Look at the doc** : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-method-of-a-form

*Just add `setAction` to form builder.*

**Extract from doc** :

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
    ->setAction($this->generateUrl('target_route'))  // <--- HERE
    ->setMethod('GET')
```